# Shared Object Mismatch due to Preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, gcc

I am building a Shared Object Project in ' IBM Rational Rhapsody 7.5 ' with qcc which in turn uses gcc .

A binary mismatch is observerd when the same code is built on two different machines having the exactly same build environment.

After some trial and error methods I observed that the mismatch is due to the pre-processsor directive used for conditional execution of code (Using #ifdef).When the pre-processor directive is removed and the project is built on different machines.The two binaries match exactly.

Is there is any reason for 'Why this mismatch occurs ?.

Is Pre-Processor directive adding machine dependent parameters in object file and so they are reflected in Executable, giving the mismatch ?
Please guide me.

Comment: What code is inside that `#ifdef` block? It's impossible to tell what the problem is without knowing that.

Comment: What symbol does the directive test for?

Comment: There must be some difference between two environments, maybe CPU type, OS version, kernel version, compiler version, or something else. You should check it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor directive `#ifdef` does conditional compilation. Whether or not this leads to binary incompatibility depends on what's between `#ifdef` and the corresponding `#endif`. For example, the following would obviously not have any effect at all:

```
#ifdef FOO
#endif
```

No matter whether `FOO` is defined, the compiled code looks exactly the same.

However the following will certainly cause an incompatibility:

```
#ifdef HAS_FOO_STRUCT
typedef foo foo_type;
#else
struct foo_type {};
#endif

void bar(foo_type);
```

Here, if HAS_FOO_STRUCT is defined, `bar(foo_type)` is actually `bar(foo)` and will be mangled as such. On the other hand, if `HAS_FOO_STRUCT` is not defined, `foo_type` is really a type of this name, thus `bar(foo_type)` will have that name mangled in. This there will be binary incompatibility.

Note that differences in defined macros can come from several different places. First, different compiler versions may define different macros (or define macros to different values). For example, there are macros identifying the type of system you are compiling on, and identifying the compiler version. Differences in macros can also come from system header files, which may have different `#define`s. Moreover, the build system may define macros indicating whether certain things (e.g. pre-installed libraries) were found or not found on the system.

Note that the binary incompatibility you see may well be intentional, in order to prevent running into a more subtle binary incompatibility which doesn't show up in compiling, but causes strange bugs under certain conditions.

Comment: I am trying to build the same shared library( i.e. same code) on 2 different machines having exactly same build environment(compiler version, etc..). On both the machines, the code that will be compiled will be the same, as the preprocessor directive is defined on both the machines.
If the definition of the directive is removed on both the machines, the binaries match exactly. 

How does preprocessor directive is creating a mismatch even though the code compiled will be the same on both the machines?

Comment: Do those machines also have the exact same libraries installed? Especially for libraries used by the shared library in question?

Comment: Yes the libraries used are same as well.